# Работа со строками из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте, возникла следующая проблема, я пишу свой архиватор, выполняю следующий код:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess as sp
dirk = 'C:\\python_programm'  # Каталог который нужно заархивировать
arch_dir = 'C:\\test\\test.rar'  # Каталог куда нужно положить архив и имя архива
sp.check_call('C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe a -rar {0} {1}'.format(arch_dir, dirk))  # Оператор запуска WinRAR
```

Всё прекрасно работает, затем я решил добавить долговременное хранения настроек путей в файле, выполняю следующий код:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess as sp
def backup():
    f = open('settings.txt')
    z = 0
    for x in f:
        if 'C' in x and z == 0:
            dirk = x
            z += 1
        elif 'C' in x and z > 0:
            arch_dir = x
            break
    f.close()
    sp.check_call('C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe a -rar {0} {1}'.format(arch_dir, dirk))  # Оператор запуска WinRAR
if __name__ == '__main__':
    backup()
```

Согласен, немного велосипед, суть не в этом.
Когда я беру строку из файла, она не вставляется нормально в параметры запуска WinRAR, т.е. архив не создается, выдает ошибку что не верно указан путь, я пишу путь в файле так:

```
'C:\\python_programm'
```

И вроде как он должен восприниматься как неформатированная строка, пробовал писать путь просто:

```
'C:\python_programm'
```

И далее с помощью оператора % подставлять строке формат отображения "%r", толку 0. 
Помогите пожалуйста с этой проблемой, может кодировка или ещё что, или есть ещё простые методы долговременного хранения.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужен вариант

```
C:\python_programm
```

и затем вставлять в строку с помощью `%s`, а не `%r`.

**Почему:**

Из файла вы читаете и winrar'у передаете просто последовательность символов. Там нет никаких escape последовательностей. Вы можете проверить значение строки через обычный `print`.

1) Если вы из файла читаете `'C:\\python_programm'` (вот прям это и видите в файле в текстовом редакторе), то вызовется в итоге `C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe a -rar 'C:\\python_programm'`. Попробуйте вызвать это из командной строчки - не сработает.

Поэтому в файле должно быть просто `C:\python_programm`

2) Когда вы используете формат `%r`, вызывается функция `repr()`, которая предназначена для того, чтобы получить, фактически, код, при выполнении которого получится исходное значение. Более очевидна разница между `%s` и `%r` на датах:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.date.today()
>>> print '%s' % d
2015-08-09
>>> print '%r' % d
datetime.date(2015, 8, 9)
```

Аналогично и со строками:

```
>>> s = "a\\b"
>>> print s
a\b
>>> print "%s, %r" % (s, s)
a\b, 'a\\b'
```

Поэтому при формировании строчки вызова вам нужен именно `%s`.

---

А вот когда вы пишете **в python-коде**

```
dirk = 'C:\\python_programm'
```

...то при выполнении вашей программы, Python конструирует строчку-последовательность-байтов по правилам разбора кода, и вот только тут-то нужно escape'ить спец символы. Кстати, есть неформатированные строки (`r"..."`), в которых не нужно экранировать.

Comment: Ну и напоследок, параметры в subprocess лучше передавать массивом: `check_call(["prog.exe", "param1", "param2"])`. Так и форматировать ничего не придется - просто прочитали строку из файла, передали ее как один из параметров безо всяких преобразований.